# Validate CSV file PySpark

Tags: csv, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I'm trying to validate the csv file(number of columns per each record). As per the below link, in Databricks 3.0 there is option to handle it.

http://www.discussbigdata.com/2018/07/capture-bad-records-while-loading-csv.html

```
df = spark.read
  .option("badRecordsPath", "/data/badRecPath")
  .parquet("/input/parquetFile")
```

However, I'm using 2.3 spark version and can't use the option.

Is there any way to find out the bad records in csv file while reading as part of pyspark and want to write bad records to a file.

Schema is not static as we are handling multiple tables data and can't hardcode the schema.

```
        df = spark.read.option("wholeFile", "true"). \
                        option("header", "true"). \
                        option("quote", "\""). \
                        csv("${table}/path/to/csv/file")
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what kind of records you are referring as bad records, since we cannot see your input data.
based on my assumption, lets say we have a below input file having five columns.

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
1,ABC,YYY,101,USA
2,ABC,ZZZ,102,USA
3,ABC,,,USA
4,ABC,GGG,104,USA
5,ABC,PPP,105
```

and line no. 3 has few empty columns and line no.5 has less column. so I do not want to load these two records in my dataframe.

```
PATH_TO_FILE = "file:///user/vikrant/hivespark/userinput"

df = sc.textFile(PATH_TO_FILE)\
           .mapPartitions(lambda line: csv.reader(line,delimiter=',', quotechar='"'))\
           .map(lambda x: [i for i in x if len(i)!= 0]) \
           .filter(lambda line: len(line) > 4 and line[0] != 'col1') \
           .toDF(['Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4','Col5'])


>>> df.show();
+----+----+----+----+----+
|Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4|Col5|
+----+----+----+----+----+
|   1| ABC| YYY| 101| USA|
|   2| ABC| ZZZ| 102| USA|
|   4| ABC| GGG| 104| USA|
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

and if you want to extract the bad records from your input file:

```
badrecords = sc.textFile(PATH_TO_FILE)\
           .mapPartitions(lambda line: csv.reader(line,delimiter=',', quotechar='"'))\
           .map(lambda x: [i for i in x if len(i)!= 0]) \
           .filter(lambda line: len(line) < 5 and line[0] != 'col1')

>>> badrecords.take(10)
[['3', 'ABC', 'USA'], ['5', 'ABC', 'PPP', '105']]
```

Let me know if it works for you or helps!

Comment: If I try to run that code it shows me the following error: "global name 'csv' is not defined" Could you please specify a little bit more the environment as well as the import statements required?

Comment: Ok, I got it...it was just a missing import csv statement.